Highstock : Tooltip not show in the exact points when there is a null between the value with the same X axis value
First of all, I want to have a break between value chages  in the series and here is the screen shot.
chart case
But I have a problem when the changes of value is in the same series object it's not hover the newest data point.
see at the cross hair
my cursor is on the top points but the tooltips is not appear.
this is my chart options
    datetimeChartOptions: HighchartsStocks.Options = {
        chart: {
            type: this.selectedChartType,
            zoomType: 'xy',
        } as Highcharts.ChartOptions,
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            },
            {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1W'
            },
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        time: {
            useUTC: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            type: 'datetime',
            crosshair: true,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '%e %B %Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            crosshair: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Price'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            line: {
                findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
                stickyTracking: false,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 4
                }
            },
            column: {
                pointWidth: 3
            },
        },
        lang: {
            noData: "No data to display"
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '15px',
                color: '#303030'
            }
        },
        series: [],
    };

Here is the similar case :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-chart-w5vbys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
see at line 25
My expectation is like this :
the tooltips is appear when it's not in the same series object
I want the "U" tooltips is appear in the 2 points. Are there any options that I need to changes to fix this problem?
FYI, i use angular.
Thanks!

Could you please provide a minimal reproducible demo? Solely judging by the provided config, it is hard to tell what can be wrong. You can start by editing given example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-chart-q7izte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here is the similar case :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-chart-w5vbys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
I have line type but want to break the line within a null, but the point on the top cannot show the tool tips. @jedrzejruta

The point after null value at line 25 ([2,3]) can't be hovered

This happens because the tooltip in Highcharts Stock is set by default to split, meaning that when there are multiple points from the same series, it will only choose the first one to highlight. In order to get rid of this behaviour, you can disable the split tooltip: demo
